# Spring boot readiness probe givining out of service in kubernetes pod though locally running fine

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, health-check, readinessprobe

Both my liveness and readiness shows status up when I am testing them locally. Running my service in kubernetes is a different story. Seems like the liveness is also working fine but readiness is giving 503. I have tried to test it from my docker image which is also working fine.

configuration properties used:

```
    management.endpoint.health.probes.enabled=true
    management.endpoint.metrics.enabled=true
    management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
    management.endpoint.prometheus.enabled=true
    management.metrics.export.prometheus.enabled=true
    management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.include=*
    management.endpoint.health.group.readiness.show-details=always
    management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.include=ping
    management.endpoint.health.group.liveness.show-details=never
```

Log from pod:

```
HttpEntityMethodProcessor:116 - Writing [org.springframework.boot.actuate.health.CompositeHealth@63a928fa]
2022-09-05T11:20:08,814 TRACE [http-nio-8090-exec-3] RequestMappingHandlerAdapter:405 - Applying default cacheSeconds=-1
2022-09-05T11:20:08,815 TRACE [http-nio-8090-exec-3] DispatcherServlet:1155 - No view rendering, null ModelAndView returned.
2022-09-05T11:20:08,815 DEBUG [http-nio-8090-exec-3] DispatcherServlet:1131 - Completed 503 SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE, headers={masked}
```

The health check in manifest:

```
        readinessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health/readiness
            port: 8090
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
        livenessProbe:
          failureThreshold: 3
          httpGet:
            path: /actuator/health/liveness
            port: 8090
            scheme: HTTP
          periodSeconds: 10
          initialDelaySeconds: 60
```

I am using spring-boot 2.7.2, upgraded from 2.1.8.RELEASE

Comment: Please provide the manifest as well

Comment: @Thomas do you mean the dependencies ?

Comment: can you please provide the manifest ?

Comment: not generating one

Comment: Your kubernetes manifest